# Switch items between two QListWidgets in python

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

i am currently designing a QT-gui in Python and i want to allow the user to switch QListWidgetItems between two QListWidgets. Multiple selection (CTRL) is allowed and switching is done by two control buttons.

In the QT4-Designer the lists looks like [this](http://uploadpic.net/2EI2.png)

So if the user selects for example two items from the left list and clicks on the '>' Button the items have to be added to the right list and consequently deleted from the left list.

My current triggered Button-Events look like this:

```
def switchR( self ):
    itemlistSel = self.list_left.selectedItems()
    for item in itemlistSel:
        self.list_right.addItem( item )
        self.list_left.removeItemWidget( item )
```

But nothing happens? Someone got a quick solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `removeItemWidget()` method doesn't quite do what you're expecting it to do (see [docs](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QListWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QListWidget.removeItemWidget)). Use `takeItem()`, `addItem()` and `row()` instead:

```
def switch(self):
    items = self.left.selectedItems()
    for item in items:
        n = self.left.row(item)    # get the index/row of the item
        i = self.left.takeItem(n)  # pop
        self.right.addItem(i)      # add to right QListWidget
```

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks for the quick answer. Additional thanks for the doc-link as it seems as i used the wrong documentation up to now.